# Compilers and MSB identification for Data types

Tags: memory, c18

I would like to know two things that is making my head quite confusing these days.

If i allocate an `int` in `C18 compiler` I know it will take two bytes and, if I initialize a pointer to the variable, say:

```
int x,*xptr;
xptr = &x;
```

then I have to access `*xptr` for first byte and `*xptr+1` for the second byte?

Well, what factor determines that which one is MSB and LSB?

Comment: The question is not related to electrical engineering, this should have been posted in stack overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order is defined by the compiler. If you look at the  [MPLAB C18 C Compiler User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf) and search for "endianness" on page 12 you'll find:

> Endianness refers to the ordering of bytes in a multi-byte value. MPLAB C18 stores data in little-endian format. Bytes at lower addresses have lower significance (the value
>   is stored “little-end-first”).

So in your example `*xptr` will reference the LSB and `*xptr+1` will reference the MSB.

Answer (score 1):

The 'endianness'. Generally speaking - it should not matter.

If you want upper and lower bytes of a word do something like:

```
unsigned int a = 1234;
unsigned char upper;
unsigned char lower;

upper = (a>>8)&0xFF;
lower = a & 0xFF;
```

and the reverse:

```
unsigned char upper = 12;
unsigned char lower = 34;
unsigned int a = 0;
a |= upper;
a <<= 8;
a |= lower;
```

This will ensure your code works reguardless of the compiler/cpu/endian.

Comment: That is _not_ good coding practice on an embedded system - the compiler is all too likely to do _exactly_ what you have told it to and implement some very expensive (in terms of time & processor cycles) operations.  Much better to do as the OP originally suggested.

Comment: It would be a very poor compiler indeed that did not convert multiplication and division by 256 into left and right shift operations. However, I agree that this is poor coding practice. If your intention is to shift bits then use a shift operation. If your intention is to merge bit fields then use an OR operation, not an addition.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. It isn't over mul add vs shift/or, its about not assuming endian. I could re-write it with shift/or of course. Once people assume endian, then they start doing things like... assume padding alignment etc.